# I try to acces a array in a for loop but i get a index error

Tags: python

I try to make a for loop and it worked but at the end i get the same error every time.
Can somebody help me?

```
def function(List, Key):
    geteilt = np.array_split(List, Key)
    for i in range(len(List)):
        for l in range(Key):
            print(geteilt[l][i])
```

Output:

```
H
H
H
H
H
I
I
I
I
I
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 18>()
     15 key = 5
     16 geteilt = np.array_split(Liste2, key)
---> 18 decoden(Liste2, key)

Input In [1], in decoden(liste, schlüssel)
      5 for i in range(len(liste)):
      6     for l in range(schlüssel):
----> 7         print(geteilt[l][i])

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Comment: Don't use [List](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.List) to name variables, it's confusing in the best case.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is either use the debugger or simple print statements to understand the nature of the problem. Also, you should provide an exemplary input.

If you call `function([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)` and look at `geteilt`,
you can see that it created 3 arrays:

`[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7])]`

So the first error is to iterate over `len(List)` which has 7 elements in this case, but neither `geteilt` nor any of the subarrays fulfill this length.
The second error is to loop over `Key` which refers to the number of splits and generally **not** the number of elements in each split.

While i'm unsure what you are trying to accomplish with these loops, if you just want to iterate over the arrays in a nested for-loop you need to adjust the `range`s:

```
def function(List, Key):
    geteilt = np.array_split(List, Key)
    for i in range(len(geteilt)):
        for l in range(len(geteilt[i])):
            print(geteilt[i][l])
```

Note that I also switched the order of indices in the last line.

Comment: I write the code for decode a Sentence with a key.
So for the Input "HIHIHIHI" and the Key 4 the output must be "HHHHIIII".
In this case the Output will be the same input as output ("HIHIHIHI";"HIHIHIHI") with the key 4.